# Video recorder for Skype and Viber

Tags: video, screen-recording, voice-recording, skype

I am looking for video/voice recorder software for Skype and Viber:

- Freeware
- Windows
- Actively developing /no abadonware
- No spyware/crapware: common AV software should not recognize download site /downloaded installer/installed software as virus/malware/spyware
- No WUP/Ransomware/Shovelware
- No subscriptions etc. Free should be forever
- Recording should be started automatically after with record type choosing (video / audio). I.e. you can also record audio in video call
- The software should be actually designed/optimized for Skype/Viber. As I mentioned simple screen recorder are not very suitable/optimized for audio/video call recording
- Stable. Every call should be /can be recorded. It should be clearly identifiable if video call record has been started.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voice spy for Windows](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26059/voice-spy-for-windows)

Comment: @4mohit but this question is *much* better than the other one! That one may as well be deleted IMO... but your answer there is good so I dunno...

Comment: I don't like the idea to close a good question in favor of a closed low-quality question – though I admit they're related. I've flagged this for our mods so they might possibly "merge" the two – effectively moving @4mohit's answer over here and "making the other page disappear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a VoIP recorder specifically for skype then [**Pamela**](http://www.pamela.biz/en/) would be the best option. Its Feature Includes

> Free Skype Call Recording 
> Skype Chat Recording
>   Record calls
>   automatically
>   Skype Conference Call manager
>   Answering Machine
>   Auto
>   Chat Reply
>   Email Forwarding
>   Blogging & Podcasting
>   Free Skype Video
>   Recording
>   Skype Call Scheduler
>   Mono/Stereo recording option
>   Create
>   cool mood messages
>   Play sounds during calls
>   Birthday Reminders
>  
>   Contact Personalization

The free basic version allows up to 15 minutes voice recording per call and 5 minutes of video recording per call. Paid versions have tons of features and unlimited recording.

And another software you may want to look at is [**Total Recorder**](http://www.totalrecorder.com/index.htm). This software is to recording everything that is happening on your PC whether its a VoIP, Sound passing through sound cards, Streaming audio or local audio and click sound open sound just about everything. Sounds are recorded both in compressed and uncompressed(FLAC) formats. Although the free basic version allows up to 60 Seconds voice recording per call only. :(

Hope this resolves your issue!!! Cheers!!